# Null Check Operator still returns a null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to get all of the generic service from my dependency injector who implement a type

```
protected List<ServiceDescriptor> GetGenericServicesFromGenericTypeDefinition(IServiceCollection services, Type baseGenericTypeDefinition)
{
    if(false == baseGenericTypeDefinition.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Invalid Argument {nameof(baseGenericTypeDefinition)}");
    }

    //TODO:  check the base type recursively
    var genericImplementations = services.Where(s => s?.ImplementationType.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType ?? false)
            .ToList();
    //.... Omitted unrelated to issue
}
```

The wierd thing is that when it tries to create genericImplementations List I receive an Error

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.'

I've checked the service it is not null, the Implementation type is however. How is this possible, Is this some how related to how the func is constructed?
[image]

**EDIT**
How am I using the Elvis Operator wrong? s has a value as you can see.  from the picture.  The error is generating from the type checked how is this possible?

Comment: Show the stacktrace. We have no idea where the exception came from otherwise.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think it's described pretty well.  When getting genericImplementations he has a service in serviceCollection that is not null, but has null ImplementationType.  I can guess where it's going to throw

Comment: even though you're checking if service is null it's properties aren't guarantied to not be null, so you need to add the elvis operator for every property

Comment: @LordWilmore: even if it's clear for you, everyone should always post the complete stacktrace. Especially if you use LINQ queries. Of course you can put a `?` everywhere. But you should understand what caused the exception before doing so. Maybe the approach is wrong and you just hide the bug with the `null-conditonal`-operator.

Comment: Are you getting list in services or is it simply null?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `?.` operator refers only to the dereferencing operation it is applied to. When not only `s` can be `null`, but also `s.ImplementationType`, the expression...

```
s?.ImplementationType.GetTypeInfo()
```

...won't be enough. You need to use the operator in all places where the expression *to the left* can be `null`:

```
s?.ImplementationType?.GetTypeInfo()
```

Since the return of `GetTypeInfo()` can not be `null`, it is enough to write:

```
s?.ImplementationType?.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType ?? false
```

It's a good idea not to generally apply the `?.` to all dereferences, but to use it only when the value could be null and skipping the rest of the expression is OK. If you apply the operator generally in all cases, errors might fall through that otherwise would get caught early.

Comment: Thanks for you're help. I couldn't believe I over looked that

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the null check operator at every member access and member call to propagate the nulls from any level, like this:

```
var genericImplementations = services.Where(s => s?.ImplementationType?.GetTypeInfo()?.IsGenericType ?? false).ToList();
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. I don't think null check for all is not required. What if services itself is null.

Comment: Thanks, I think I just really need it after Implementation Type